# Touchsreen always returns cursor to upper left corner

Tags: 11.04, xorg, cursor, touchscreen, evdev

Just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on a brand new Fujitsu Lifebook T901. The touchscreen seems well-calibrated and recognizes touches, but it always moves the mouse to the upper left corner when clicked.

XInput test looks something like this:

```
motion a[0]=1110 a[1]=632 a[2]=0 a[3]=3 
button press   1 
motion a[0]=0 a[1]=0 a[2]=0 a[3]=0 
button release 1
```

(The mouse always moves back to the origin before it is released)

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I simply upgraded to 11.10 on my T901 and the touch screen worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Fujitsu_Lifebook_T901 the ID of your touchscreen is **056a:00e6**

And according to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708307 it should be fixed in 2.6.38.8-35+ kernels. Comment the bug if it's not.

Also you can check these links:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html

And mark the question as answered if it works again.
I've had the same behavior with Impression Impad 1410.

Comment: I've changed the answer so the links are only additional. And there are a lot of text that is being updated frequently (it is already edited to contain Android 4.0 information, for example). Do you still think we need that content here?

Comment: Should be okay now, unless the poster asks for additional clarification. Thanks!